# Java controller code runs even after returning

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I am having an issue which my team and I have been debugging for hours without any clue to why my code is not executing in order,

The issue now is that in my controller I call two main functions, function 1 checks for payment and if payment is not successful, it throws an error which will be propagated to my controller which catches it and returns a 302 to redirect to an error page. However, based on my logs, my code executed function 2 which is saving the user details into my database first before checking for the payment response

My team is unable to replicate this behaviour in our dev and uat environment and this issue only occurs in production, in production, the code repeatedly runs the function 2 first based on the logs printed before returning the error page to the users,

Could this be a code issue or a server setting issue that is causing this? App is hosted on cloud foundry with autoscaling with two instances by default

Code of my controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> executePayment(
        @ModelAttribute PaymentRequestDto paymentRequestDto,
        @RequestParam("sessionId") String sessionId,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    GrafanaUtils.addToThreadContextTraceGroupId(sessionId);
    MpgsPayApiResponseDto mpgsPayApiResponseDto;

    String hashedCode = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((sessionId.getBytes()));
    response.addCookie(CookieUtils.generateCookie(Constants.REDIRECT_COOKIE_ID, hashedCode));

    // Call MPGS
    try {
        // error thrown from this service
        mpgsPayApiResponseDto = authenticationService.executePayment(paymentRequestDto, sessionId); 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        GrafanaUtils.addToThreadContextTraceGroupId(ExceptionConstants.MPGS_CONNECTION_EXCEPTION, ex);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND)
                .location(URI.create(paymentUiBaseUrl.concat(paymentUiErrorPath))).build(); // should return here 
    }

    // MPGS Success
    // should never reach here if above code throws exception and return
    // however code still runs after above throws error and return error page
    try {
        authenticationService.savePaymentDetails(mpgsPayApiResponseDto, sessionId);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("[executePayment] Error saving payment details");
    }

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND)
            .location(URI.create(paymentUiBaseUrl.concat(paymentUiConfirmPath))).build();
}
```

Code of my service:

```
public MpgsPayApiResponseDto executePayment(PaymentRequestDto paymentRequestDto, String sessionId) {
    if (!("PROCEED").equals(paymentRequestDto.getResponse().getGatewayRecommendation())) {
        MpgsPayApiResponseDto mpgsPayApiResponseDto = mpgsService.retrieveTransaction(paymentRequestDto.getOrder().getId(),
                paymentRequestDto.getTransaction().getId());
        savePaymentDetails(mpgsPayApiResponseDto, sessionId);
        log.info("[executePayment] Session {}: Error making payment ", sessionId);
        throw new CustomException(ExceptionConstants.MPGS_CONNECTION_EXCEPTION); // code returns here
    }

    ...

    return mpgsPayApiResponseDto;
}
```

Comment: `authenticationService.executePayment` calls `savePaymentDetails(mpgsPayApiResponseDto, sessionId)`? are you sure that this is what you expect? If `savePaymentDetails` prints anything, it should show up 2 times according to your description. If its just once, then it executes as you programmed it

Comment: What you described is not possible. Perhaps some extra logging statements would help you find out what is really happening

Comment: Yes, I think we missed something really big, however we confirmed that after receiving the error page, the users are still added into our database. Will add more logging to verify tomorrow